# Ocultar um app ou bat em execução

Tags: batch

quero chamar um aplicativo atravez do bat e ocultar da bandeja
escrevi o script

```
@echo off/hid
star/min 'NOME DO APLICATIVO'
exit
```

salvei como start.bat>>>> porém quando eu executo ele inicia o app esconde o cmd minimiza o app mais não oculta da bandeja ... ja tentei trocar start/min por start/hid mais aparece invalido... como faço isso ?

Answer (score 2):

A única solução que eu sei é usando **VBS**.

Abra o bloco de notas e coloque o seguinte código:

```
Dim wshShell
Set wshShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
wshShell.Run "seusscript.bat", 0, false
```

No lugar de *seusscript.bat* coloque o caminho do seu **BATCH SCRIPT**, depois salve com o nome que quiser mas com a extensão *vbs*:

```
start.vbs
```

Deve ficar com ícone assim:

[image: Icon VBS]

Basta clicar duas vezes olhar no gerenciador de tarefas (Ctrl+Alt+Del) pra ver que o Script está realmente rodando.

Answer (score 1):

Utilize o comando abaixo:

```
start "" "CAMINHO\Aplication.exe"
```

Segue referência [AQUI](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12848306/1708246)